# Get list value filed1 by list value field2 from Mongo(SpringData)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I have collection in Mongo:

```
[{ "_id": 1, "book": "aaa", "author": "James", "seller": "Tom"},
{ "_id": 2, "book": "bbb", "author": "James", "seller": "James"},
{ "_id": 3, "book": "ccc", "author": "Mary", "seller": "Mary"},
{ "_id": 4, "book": "ddd", "author": "Mary", "seller": "James"}]
```

I want to get list with value of field **"book"** by field **"_id"**.
For example: `[1,2] -> ["aaa", "bbb"]`
*How I can do this with using Spring Data? or what query need for this?*

Answer (score 0):

Try this(***Not Tested***):

```
@Repository
public interface YourClassNameRepository extends MongoRepository<YourClassName, String> {

     @Query(value = "{'_id' : ?0}", fields = "{'book' : 1}")
     List<YourClassName> loadBookNames(List<String> ids);
}
```

And this will return you a list of `YourClassName`objects where only `book`fields will be populated.